# Titre de séjour about to expiré and lost the job

Tags: france

I am working here in France since May 2015 with passport talent titre de sejour. I changed my job and joined a French company in Jan 2021, thus I had to change my titre de sejour.
Currently I have "CARD DE SEJOUR TEMPORAIRE" which is valid till Oct 2021.
Today I got call from my HR that they are terminating my contract (I am on probation period).

My question is: **Will I be able to renew my "CARD DE SEJOUR " even though I don't have the job?**

Comment: Are you British and are you affected by the Brexit Withdrawal Agreement? If not, what is your nationality? Please [edit] your question accordingly rather than just add to the comment trail.